# Windows Azure Facebook Token

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Windows Azure Mobile Services to log in using facebook. Once the user logs in I have the token but when I try to use this token with the facebook client I get a bad signature exeption.

Isnt it supposed to be the same token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you getting the FB token? The token you receive from the mobile services client is the *Azure Mobile Services token*, and you can't use it with FB. To get the FB access token, you need to get it via a server script (with the `user.getIdentities()` function), as shown at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx.

Another alternative is to use the Facebook SDK directly, which will give you a FB token (and you can then use that token to log in to Azure Mobile Services directly. The post at http://ntotten.com/2013/03/14/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-with-the-facebook-sdk-for-windows-phone/ has some information on how this can be done.